# Insert Into table through a select statement which returns more Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there is a way to Insert Values into the table through a select statement which returns few additional columns that are not present in the INSERT clause values but I need those additional values to use it in my OUTPUT clause. I am not really sure about how OUTPUT clause works in this case.

For example, This is my requirement

```
INSERT INTO TABLE testA(a,b,c)
OUTPUT INSERTED.a, x INTO tempTable (a,x)
SELECT (x,a,b,c) FROM testB
```

*Sample Data ex:*

`testB` has a row with column values a=A b=B c=C and x=1
Now I want testA to have A,B,C columns inserted and 
tempTable to have A,1 to be inserted into it.

Can I get some help in achieving it?

Help very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you add some simple sample data please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a column in `OUTPUT` list which is not present in Destination table.

`INSERTED` table will have whatever values will be newly inserted into destination table

If `x` is a constant then hardcode the value in `Output` list

```
INSERT INTO TABLE testA
            (a,b,c)
OUTPUT      INSERTED.a,
            1
INTO tempTable (a, x)
SELECT a,b,c
FROM   testB
```

Comment: WOW!!! So even if the select statement doesn't have x in the statement, INSERTED.x contains that ? Can you please educate me on how this works..